# Is there a way to stop a push notification with Firebase or can I set an expire notification time?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented push notifications in my Android app using Firebase. I can retrieve the token and send messages using Firebase, but I want to know if there is a way to disconnect the notifications, with a timer, or something similar?

Comment: You can use `data` type of messages instead `notification` type and solve when show or don't push in client code.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [`time_to_live`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) parameter:

> This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline. The maximum time to live supported is 4 weeks, and the default value is 4 weeks. For more information, see [Setting the lifespan of a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl).

Easy as the description says, it's like setting an expiration date. If the message is not yet delivered during that time, FCM discards it.

But if you intend to simply have the app to stop notifications altogether, you could:

- Simply stop sending towards the corresponding registration token.
- Implement a *Push notification settings* in your app, where if false (and if you're app is the one handling the push notification) have the method disabled.
- Lastly, call `deleteInstanceId()`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197589/4625829).