# How is possible to support multi-users Android app with FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM registration generates a registration token that is associated with the device and not a particolar user. So, how to handle two common scenarios:

- **Logout**: A logged in user is supposed to receieve notification, until he logs out
- **Switch user**: If after logging out a new user logs in, it should have a different registration token that does't interfeer with the previous one.

This is an old documentation (from GCM)

> Developers should never unregister the client app as a mechanism for
> logout or for switching between users, for the following reasons:
>
> A registration token isn't associated with a particular logged in
> user. If the client app unregisters and then re-registers, the app can
> receive the same registration token or a different registration token.
>
> Unregistration and re-registration may each take up to five minutes to
> propagate. During this time messages may be rejected due to the
> unregistered state, and messages may go to the wrong user.

Of course GCM now is deprecated, but it is likely that the same rules described here applies.

So, what are the possible ways for handling the two aforementioned scenarios? I could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a common situation. Here is one way to handle it or here is how things at my end are handled.

In the Login API, I use the following to generate a new FCM token and that is sent every time in the Login API

```kotlin
Firebase.messaging.token.addOnSuccessListener { fcmToken -> }
```

So whenever a new Sign-In or Login is performed, the `fcmToken` goes in its own keys and replaces the already existing one at backend.

Coming to logout situation now. When we log-out, we call this code to delete the token associated with device thus ensuring no more notifications are received when logged-out.

```kotlin
Firebase.messaging.deleteToken()
```

Further more as another level of check in the `FirebaseMessagingService` `onMessageReceived` method call, we have added a check to see if user is already logged in or not then and only anything else is performed.

Comment: So basically the backend changes the mapping user <--> token.
If you login with user1 and the generated token is token1, then the backend will keep that association in the db. If then you logout and log-in with user2, then even if the token generated is the same, you change the association in the db to 
user1 <--> null and user2 <--> token1 ?

Comment: If I login with `user1` and generate `token1` that passes on to backend and they keep track of it user1 to token1. When I logout, `token1` gets deleted. If I try to login again with `user2` new `token2` is generated and those get linked as in user2 to token2. If I logout again, the token gets deleted again. Whenever I relogin with any user the new token replaces the one at backend.

Comment: But are you sure that a new token is always generated? Cause based on that old documentation there is no guarantee about that.

Comment: @GVillani82 store token in sharedpref

Comment: I understand your concern. You might want to check this [link out](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId). The class in question is deprecated now, but you can see the situations under which the `token` or `instanceId` is stable and whenever you delete the token a new unique one is generated as far as I know @GVillani82

Comment: Thank you @che10 I will take a look at that

Comment: @GVillani82  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386448/when-to-register-an-fcm-token-for-a-user
please check the top answer and its 2nd point. it seems you have the same problem about getting token of new user.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan. I saw that answer, but I am still not sure about what he says: "Then the new user signs in, they will then get a new token.", cause the documentation doesn't say that, and the old documentation (GCM) explicitally says that the same token may be generated.

Comment: @GVillani82 have you checked the link which I have posted in my answer. Its very detailed. Please have a look, it might be resolved your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974658/how-to-put-multiple-project-number-sender-id-in-google-services-json/37981412#37981412

Look at this too.

Comment: @MuhammadZahabAhmadKhan that's something different. There they are talking about multiple senders

Comment: @GVillani82 I think you will be fine. Deleting a token will generate a new unique one and thus as long as you delete it on logout and make sure the backend replaces the token received on every login. You will be fine and will be able to support multiple users.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try @che10  You also handle the `onNewToken` I guess. 
I am also wondering if calling `Firebase.messaging.token` multiple times will not affect the generated token, once a token is already available. Correct?

Comment: I believe so @GVillani82 You can also probably test this hypothesis by generating token again and printing it to log. As I said in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId) it mentions the scenario under which the token remains stable and unless it is one of those situations the token will still be the same.