# How to turn on/off firebase notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented firebase push notification and it is working fine. But now I have one requirement that on the toggle button in application I need to on/off the firebase notifications. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: You can easily implement that by using `SharedPreferences` storing Boolean `true` or `false` on toggle button. And with retrieving the value from `SharedPreferences` according is toggle button on or off subscribe or unsubscribe to Firebase notifications.

Comment: @Yupi You are talking about subscribe and unsubscribe topic here, right?

Comment: Yes I meant on that.

Comment: I posted an answer if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Similarly to [handling logouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197589/4625829), but instead, you disable the push notifs on a toggle. If you're using `data` message payloads only, then you should be fine with just disabling the Notification builder only.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement that by using `SharedPreferences` storing Boolean `true` or `false` on toggle button. And with retrieving the value from `SharedPreferences` according is toggle button on or off subscribe or unsubscribe to Firebase notifications. For example:
For toggle switch:

```
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean("key", true).apply();
    } else {
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putBoolean("key", false).apply();

       }
   }
});
```

And to get stored values:

```
 boolean isSubscribed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                    .getBoolean("key", false);
            if(isSubscribed)
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic('news');
            else
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic('news');
```