# Delivering Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications to specific Firebase Users

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

this is a bit of a composite question, I'll try my best to separate the various parts even if they all have a common intent.

## Common intent

Having a clear way of delivering notifications about posts regarding specific topics to Firebase Users (and not simply to application instances).

I have tried various methods, and I can't find a definitive answer about which one is the best one.

## Method 1 - Relying only on the database

Each Firebase User has its own document in the Firestore at `users/{userId}`

This document contains two collections: tokens and interests.

The token collection contains a list of documents which have FCM tokens as one of their fields. Each time an user signs in the application or `FirebaseInstanceIDService.onTokenRefresh()` is called, the collection is updated to add the new token.

The interest collection contains a list of interests which simply are strings and are used as tags for posts. This collection has a mirror as `interests/{interestId}/users/{userId}` showing all the users interested in something. (This is kept updated and synchronised via a Cloud Function)

When a new post is created under a specific interest, I can get a list of all the users interested and then get their tokens from their document. Finally, I send a notification to each individual token.

### Problems

- This solution is not elegant (this isn't that big of a problem)
- With the new GDPR rules I fear I might not be allowed to save tokens
  directly on the Database
- If the user signs out when he's offline, the
  token isn't removed from his document, and the new user receives
  notifications for the old interests.
- Should I keep track of what the current token is and update it each time an user signs in ignoring `FirebaseInstanceIDService.onTokenRefresh()`? Else only the user signed in when the service is called would update the database.

## Method 2 - Using FCM topic subscriptions

This should be the best option for me, but I can't understand how to make it work with multiple users on the same phone (always one at a time though)

The way I would handle this is still have the `users/{userId}/interests` collection, removing `users/{userId}/tokens` and `interests/{interestId}/users`, and subscribe/unsubscribe from the various topics as the user signs in and out.

### Problems

- What happens if the user signs out when he's offline? There is no way to retrieve the current subscriptions and remove each one, potentially resulting in conflicting topics subscriptions.

---

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: See my answer on [handling logouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197589/4625829)

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing it and so far it's working well.