# FCM - cannot receive notifications sent from the same device after logging in as a different user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

I'm sending notifications from my Flask server using [PyFCM](https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM), and I'm testing it on a single Android device. The test is like this: I am signed in as user A, and I make a comment on a post of user B which should display a push notification once B signs in. Here is how I send the notification from my server:

```
registration_id="<device_registration_id>"
message_body = "A has commented on your post."
data_message = {"sender": current_user.id}
result =  push_service.notify_single_device(
    registration_id=registration_id,
    message_body=message_body,
    data_message=data_message
)
```

And this is how I receive the message in the Android's Firebase messaging service:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT):

    String senderId = remoteMessage.getData().get("sender");
    if (senderId != currentUser.id) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default_channel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android_icon)
            .setContentTitle("New Comment")
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundURI)
            .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

        NoticationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }  
}
```

As you can see, I have this condition: `senderId != currentUser.id` before actually composing the notification. It's because I'm using one device to send and receive the notification so there's only one registation_id/token for both users A and B. If I remove that condition, user A will receive the notification right after commenting on B's post. I want to ensure that B is the one who receives the notification. However, after logging out as A and logging in as B, I couldn't see any push notification.

Comment: Hi Bargain23. I'm not quite sure where the issue is here. Are you not receiving the message at all (`onMessageReceived` not triggered) or is it that the message is received and for some reason, it is not passing your `senderId != currentUser.id` condition?

Comment: @AL. Actually, `senderId != currentUser.id` condition was put in place to make sure that no two users of the same device will receive the notification.

Comment: Err. I get that part. What I don't understand is are you able to trigger `onMessageReceived` or not?

Comment: @AL. I think onMessageReceived is only being triggered once. Say, I'm trying to send a notification from my server to all users, and I receive it while logged in as A. I clear the notification tray, log out, and log in as B, but I don't see another instance of the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I think onMessageReceived is only being triggered once. Say, I'm trying to send a notification from my server to all users, and I receive it while logged in as A. I clear the notification tray, log out, and log in as B, but I don't see another instance of the notification.*

This is working as intended. From your post, I assume that you are not specifically deleting the registration token i.e. users of the same device *re-use* the same token. So the flow now looks like this:

1. User A signs in, so deviceToken = A.
2. You send a message from your server to deviceToken.
3. deviceToken receives the message, **but** you do not display it.
4. User A signs out, User B signs in, now deviceToken = B. Note: Same deviceToken, just different user.

In step 4, you're still expecting a message to arrive, but technically, it already did when User A was still signed in. `onMessageReceived` won't trigger again since it already received the message as expected.

In order to test your desired behavior, you would need two devices. I'm also actually doing this to an app I made (checking the senderId with the currentUser id), so I think it should work as well for you.

Also, the usual and suggested flow with FCM when signing out is you have to invalidate the token -- see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43193215/4625829) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. One thing, though, if I invalidate a device token when a user has logged out, and during this period, how will I be able to send him a notification knowing that his token has been invalidated?

Comment: After the token has been invalidated, `onTokenRefresh()` should trigger, wherein you could call `getToken()` again and store that new token to your server. The token however, will not be associated to a specific user, until such time that another one signs in.