# Disable app using Firebase messaging remotely?

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to stop all Firebase Cloud Messaging functionality from my app completely. How can I do it? Does removing the Firebase project prevent the app from using all the Firebase Messaging related functionality? I tried disabling the Firebase Cloud Messaging API from Google's API console but it reenables itself automatically next I sent push notification using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I just want to disable all Firebase Cloud Messaging related functionality from all versions of my app without creating another APK.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to stop all the servcices of firebse in your running app there are 2 ways to stop them ;-

1) remove all the SHA from firebase console.
2) Delete your firebase project from firebase console.

Comment: Problem is if I remove the Firebase Project and it doesn't stop it. I will lose access to remote config and remote database too which prevents unauthorized users from using the app right now. I want to be sure before doing it.

Comment: if you don't want to delete project then remove all the SHA from your firebase project.

Comment: It doesn't work. I removed SHA from the project. I can still receive Firebase Cloud Messaging push notification.

Comment: i search about your question on google and i found an answer i think it may be solve you proble :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193215/firebase-cloud-messaging-handling-logout/43197589#43197589

Comment: I can't provide new version of the apk. I want to do this to stop the app from working. That means all the previous version of app must stop too.

Comment: now the final step is you can delete your project from firebase and it will surely stop your all services

Comment: I'm gonna try that with test project first.

Comment: if my answer helps you then please appreciate the answer

Comment: I tried removing Firebase Project but it still works normally. It may be due to the multiple sender feature of Firebase Messaging that I use. I contacted Google about this.