# Can we use deleteToken method in Firebase Messaging Android? Is this documented in Google anywhere

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just want to get new token from firebase whenever i sign in with different user. Currently, My app is supporting user enrollment with different users so Im facing a problem where i received push notification even if i trigger notification for previously enrolled user when app is enrolled with different user..
So i want to pass new token always as suggested by my third part vendor. In order to do this, I want to create new token whenever i enroll new user.

I just want to try deleteToken but not sure whether this is officially documented in google fcm developer site. Also do i need to call deleteInstanceID method along with deleteToken method?

Comment: I'm not sure what type of documentation you're looking for, but `deleteToken` is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#deleteToken(). You can also look at other questions where folks asked or answer about `deleteToken()` here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-cloud-messaging%5D%5Bandroid%5D+deleteToken For example, this looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193215/firebase-cloud-messaging-handling-logout