# How to force refresh an FCM token in Flutter using firebase_messaging package

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-security

Using `firebase_messaging: ^13.0.2` I'm unsure how to force a refresh of the FCM token... without logging the user out. I noticed it refreshes when signing out + back in.

According to google docs there are only 3 ways to refresh the token:

- The app is restored on a new device
- The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
- The user clears app data.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens

What I run on startup as a listener:

```
FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
tokenStream = firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      print('token $event');
      currentUser!.fcmToken = event;
      FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUserfcmToken(currentUser!);
    }
  });
```

---

How to force a refresh of this token? This does not work and produces the same token value as before the delete was run...

```
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken().then((value) =>
              FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) {
                currentUser!.fcmToken = value;
                FireStoreUtils.updateCurrentUserfcmToken(currentUser!);
              }));
```

---

**If you're wondering why I want to refresh, see my other post here:** [IOS notifications stop working until FCM token refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74061401/ios-notifications-stop-working-until-fcm-token-refresh)

Answer (score 4):

Did you try by **deleting token** using this method?

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken()
```

if this is not helping you can try delete token first and request new token then you will received new event for new token in onTokenRefresh

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.deleteToken().then((value) => FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken());
```

This will sure generate new token I tested.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This did not refresh the token

Comment: See my latest edit. That does not work

Comment: The token is the same value as before the delete was run...

Comment: Are you testing on iPhone or Android? Because I just tested on android.

Comment: Testing on Android

Answer (score 0):

According to Ready Android,To get a new refreshed FCM token (forcefully).

> Blockquote
> To get a new refreshed FCM token (forcefully), first you have to delete it and then request for FCM token again. It will always provide a new token after once deletion.

in this link : [How to refresh FCM Token on user Logout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138300/how-to-refresh-fcm-token-on-user-logout)